# What is a==b==c in C?

Tags: c, comparison, operators

```
int main()
{
    int a=0,b=0,c=0;

    if (a==b==c)
    {
         printf("111\n");
    }
    else
    {
         printf("222\n");
    }
    if (a==b)
    {
         printf("333");
    }
}
```

The output is

```
222
333
```

It's very clearly that, a==b==c is **False** and a==b is **True**.
But I couldn't find the reason.
I guess maybe a==b==c is match variables' address.
I need more clue and proof.

Comment: `a == b == c` is `(a == b) == c` is either `0 == c` or `1 == c` (in the case that `a` and `b` have the same value ... is `1 == c`). The equality operator `==` yields an `int` with the value `0` or `1`.

Comment: It's about operator *associativity*. For the `==` operator it's left to right which leads to the situation mentioned by @pmg.

Comment: Just don't write code such as `a == b == c`. Weird code gives weird results.

Comment: very frequent dupe. You should use SO search box above.

Answer (score 2):

In C, `a == b == c` is equivalent to `(a == b) == c`, where `a == b` yields 1 if true, 0 otherwise.

In your case, `a == b` is true, so `a == b == c` is equivalent to `1 == c`, which is false.

You can further try it with:

```
printf("%d\n%d\n", 0 == 0, 0 == 1);
```

which gives the result:

```
1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison operator `==` has [left to right](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm) associativity.

So, an expression like

```
 a == b == c
```

is the same as

```
(a == b ) == c
```

In your case, `a`, `b`, `c` all having values `0`, the expression turns out to be

```
(0 == 0) == 0
```

or,

```
  1 == 0
```

which yields 0 (Falsy). So, control goes to the `else` part.

Then, for the aforementioned reason, `a == b` evaluates to `1` (truthy), so the corresponding `if` block is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The equality operator evaluates left to right and yields `1` if the
specified equality is true and `0` if it is false.

Thus the expression in the if statement

```
if (a==b==c)
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( ( a == b ) == c )
```

As `a` is equal to `b` (the both are equal to `0` ) then the first sub-expression `( a == b )` evaluates to 1 and you actually have

```
if ( 1 == c )
```

As c is equal to 0 then the expression `1 == c` evaluates to 0 and the compound statement of the if statement is bypassed. As a result the sub-statement of the else statement is executed

```
printf("222\n");
```

Maybe the author of the code meant the following if statement

```
if ( ( a == b ) && ( b == c ) )
```

In this case as `a` is equal to `b` and `b` is equal to `c` then this condition evaluates to logical true.

On the other hand, as `a` is equal to `b` then this if statement is also executed.

```
if (a==b)
{
     printf("333");
}
```